# Sublime Text: Detect non used files in PHP (WordPress) project?

Tags: wordpress, parsing, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Created a PHP project in Sublime Text 3 that holds PHP, CSS, JS, HTML, and some other files and folders. Other files may be .md, .txt, .ico, images and fonts (.woff, .ttf, ...).

Actually project is WordPress, but the solution should be for all PHP based projects, and specifically I am interested only to check specific folders inside of project (liek theme and plugin files). WordPress core is no interest for me to check.

I would like to detect Files with extensions (.php, .css, .js) that are unused. Is there a smart solution do detect these?

For instance CSS file is not used if no other files references it. The reference may came from another CSS file or from some PHP file, or even JS file.

I am not searching for a perfect solution, but for something that is close to detect these or even for an idea how I may think about these.

In WordPress (PHP) there are `require` and `include` instructions, and  also `wp_enqueue_script/styles` that represent the mechanism how to reference files for instance.

So we could create a list of all PHP, CSS, JS files, and then based on file names search for these in the content of all other files. This would be a good start.

Comment: I don't see why you would tag this with `sublimetext`, as Sublime Text is no part of your problem or a possible solution. Using appropriate tags will likely attract the attention of those who might be able to help.

Anyway, one thing I can think of is the use of [magic constants](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) in your files, displaying them on condition (e.g. `if (DEBUG == true): echo __FILE__;`).

Comment: Sublime Text is sublime editor, and my editor of choice,  that may have plugins for different problems. However, you just gave me the idea to think out of the box, thank you so much.